# System.Xml needed without reason

Tags: c#, .net

```
protected override DataTable internalExecuteTable(string SQL)
{
    DbDataReader reader = ExecuteReader(SQL);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

"internalExecuteTable" is underlined and throws an error that "System.Xml" is not referenced and I should add the "System.Xml" reference. But why?

I use the above code to read from an SQLite database (System.Data.SQLite wrapper)

Comment: Sometimes VisualStudio gets confused... it's cache often shows errors which don't exist. Have you tried building your solution using MSBuild directly? Have you tried closing and re-opening VisualStudio?

Comment: @JesseWebb I already tried this, but it's like the error is really an normal error. Adding System.Xml fixes this, but i still don't get why...

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the code and returning null? I wonder if it isnt the override? I know sometimes .NET has weird dependencies per Anthony's answer, but I am not sure if this is one of those cases without pulling out JustDecompile

Comment: @JustinPihony, you can reproduce this quickly. Simply bring up Visual Studio, create new project, type `var table = new DataTable();` in a simple method and compile. If you haven't done anything to the standard project, it will succeed. Next, kill the System.Xml from your references. Recompile. You should notice the error that the OP mentions.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Agreed, my VS loads slow sometimes, so was just throwing another option :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using `System.Xml` indirectly. The `DataTable` has dependencies upon classes defined in the `System.Xml` assembly. If you look at the documentation for the class or if you simply explore it in your IDE, you will note that it includes many methods for reading and writing XML, for example.

By using `System.Data.DataTable`, you also need to reference `System.Xml`.

Comment: sounds like it makes sense when you say it that way.

Comment: In this case, `DataTable` implements the `IXmlSerializable` interface, which is inside of System.Xml.dll.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable is [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) declared as

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class DataTable 
     : MarshalByValueComponent,
       IListSource,
       ISupportInitializeNotification,
       ISupportInitialize,
       ISerializable,
       IXmlSerializable
```

`IXmlSerializable` declares Methods that use `XmlReader`, `XmlWriter` and `XmlSchema` for either in- or output, all of them declared respectively defined in System.Xml.dll.

If you dive into the code (using the official sources or IL/Decompiler) you may notice an attribute usage:

```
[XmlSchemaProvider("GetDataTableSchema")]
//...
public class DataTable : //...
```

Unfortunately the MSDN guys didn't include that reference to `System.Xml` explicitly in the remarks section - maybe because the usual project templates include it anyways.